# How do I change the mouse cursor when I mouseover on a particular area in Google Map v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps API v3: How do I change the mouse cursor when I mouseover on a particular area?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by setting `draggableCursor` in MapOptions, as in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps v3 Change Cursor Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 350px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
                                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                                       zoom: 8,
                                       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.3, 150.6) 
                                    });

      var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.00, 150.00);
      var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.00, 150.50);                              
      var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.00, 150.50);
      var se = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.00, 150.00);

      var boundingBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: [ne, nw, sw, se, ne],
         strokeColor: '#FF0000'
      });

      boundingBox.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
         if ((event.latLng.lat() > se.lat()) && (event.latLng.lat() < ne.lat()) &&
             (event.latLng.lng() > ne.lng()) && (event.latLng.lng() < sw.lng())) {
            map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'crosshair' });
         }
         else {
            map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'url(http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/openhand.cur), move' });
         }
      });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

If you run the above example, the cursor would change to a cross hair once the mouse is moved inside the red rectangle.

[image: Google Maps Change Cursor]

Comment: The example doesn't work for some reason, but the code actually works when I try it in my code!

Comment: The example is just an image :)

Comment: What could I do if I use Polygon instead of polyline? draggableCursor didnt work..cursor is still pointer

Comment: If you still have the image, consider re-uploading to imgur

Comment: @Daniel One reason not to use ImageShack - your image has vanished :(

Answer (score 2):

Other answers advising to to put 'mousemove' listeners on the whole map object will work but are wrong.  This is 'heavy handed' and a bad idea as listeners like these can add up in a real application and when combined with other things happening on your map, can cause serious performance problems and possibly unforeseen race conditions!

The BEST way to do this is to use the `google.maps.Polygon` class.  This allows you to pass a series of LatLng objects to create a Polygon.  This polygon is rendered on the map and has a default mouseover attribute of 'pointer', you can add a 'mouseover' listener to the object returned from the `new google.maps.Polygon` class call.

The source below is from this example
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.html

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var bermudaTriangle;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
];

bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Then I can add the listener like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'mouseover', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
});
//now if you mouse over the Polygon area, your map will zoom to 8
```